# How to auto insert to table with trim

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a SSIS package .. it is auto inserting rows into SQL Server.

One column `user Name` has data like `1234#Anil`.

I want to insert only `Anil` in my table.

How can I do that?

Comment: You would need to use a trigger to modify the data going into the column.

Comment: You'll need to be a little more specific. Is the data always of that exact format? There are a lot of transformation objects in SSIS, and I'm sure that one of them can do what you need. Your best bet is to start with the Derived Column transformation. If the logic is complex enough then you might need to use a Script Component transformation.

Answer (score 3):

You can select the data you need from Data Source (OLE DB Source) using some built-in function or you can use Derived Column component to transform the column data as your requeriment.

1. From `select` statement in Data Source component.

   ```
   select 
       RIGHT(UserName, CHARINDEX('#', UserName) - 1) as ActualName,
       *
   from table
   ```
2. From derived column transformation expression

   ```
   RIGHT(UserName, FINDSTRING(UserName, "#", 1) - 1)
   ```

Let me know if this helps you.